# Firewall ipfw in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, ping, ipfw

I have a doubt respect to the functionality of the IPFW firewall in FreeBSD. My scenario is the following:
[image]

All these machines are running FreeBSD, and all of them are virtual machines. The thing is that I don't understand one thing. If I add a rule in IPFW in the firewall machine to block pings from machine 2 to machine 1, I don't know why this block is bidirectional. I mean, I put this rule:

```
ipfw add 02000 deny icmp from 10.0.2.2 to 10.0.1.2
```

With this I understand that the firewall will block any ICMP packet coming from `10.0.2.2` (machine on the right in the picture) to `10.0.1.2` (machine on the left in the picture), but what really happens is that ok, machine 2 cannot ping to machine 1, but machine 1 cannot ping machine 2 either! Why is that? The rules of IPFW are the following:
[image]

Pictures of the pings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What evidence do you have that the ICMP packets from machine 1 do not make it through the firewall to machine 2? Please provide details. 

`ping` would not be successful, since the return packet from machine 2 would not make it through the firewall to machine 1.

Comment: Ahh thats truee, the response of machine 2 will not arrive to machine 1 because of firewall. Thanks!!

Comment: [Don't post a screenshot of text. Copy-paste the text.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: @cherdt Since your comment is a good answer please added as one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are pinging 10.0.2.2 FROM 10.0.2.1, then the ping reply (to 10.0.2.1 FROM 10.0.2.2), is ALSO an icmp packet, so it matches the rule and is blocked.

To get your desired behaviour, change the rule to:

`ipfw add 02000 deny icmp from 10.0.2.2 to 10.0.1.2 icmptypes 8`

Where type 8 is 'echo-request', and type 0 is 'echo-reply'.

Or add a rule before 2000 to allow replies only, and continue to block all other ICMP packets:

`ipfw add 01999 allow icmp from 10.0.2.2 to 10.0.1.2 icmptypes 0
ipfw add 02000 deny icmp from 10.0.2.2 to 10.0.1.2`

Answer (score 2):

You can confirm whether or not machine 2 is receiving and responding to ICMP packets using `tcpdump`, e.g.:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
```

In the case you have described, `ping` would not be successful because the return packet from machine 2 would be blocked by the firewall on machine 1.